# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter for Cucumber with extent reports

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, extent

I am trying to generate extent report for my test case using Cucumber and Extent report using JUnit. But I am getting:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter` and
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception while running cucumber test using JUnit`

These are the dependencies which I have added to my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
        <version>1.27</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.13</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> 
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId> 
        <version>3.8.1</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And this is the exception I am getting.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.loadClass(PluginFactory.java:174)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.pluginClass(PluginFactory.java:166)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.getPluginClass(PluginFactory.java:223)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.isFormatterName(PluginFactory.java:201)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.addPlugins(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:94)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.buildArgsFromOptions(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:41)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:26)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gherkin.formatter.Reporter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 37 more
```

My runner class is as follows:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.cucumber.listener.ExtentProperties;
import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features= {"src/test/java/com/cumberpr2/First/feature"},
                 glue= {"com/cumberpr2/step"}, monochrome=true,tags= {"@bvt,@sanity"},
                 plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber/report1.html"})
public class Runner1 {

     @AfterClass
     public static void teardown() {
            Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("/cumberpr2/Extent-Config.xml"));
            //Reporter.setSystemInfo("user", System.getProperty("user.name"));
            Reporter.setSystemInfo("os", "windows OSX");
            Reporter.setTestRunnerOutput("Sample test runner output message");
     }

}
```

I am unable to figure out what is wrong.

Any suggestion to fix this will be helpful.

Comment: You may have added it to your PATH but not CLASSPATH.

Comment: @Sid added what to path ?

Comment: The class that your error stack shows.  JUnit in this case.

Comment: @Sid i am now getting "cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter. It does not implement cucumber.api.Plugin " after adding a gherkin dependency as suggested by john in below answer

Comment: @Sid i can mail you my code if you can look into it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but maybe adding this to your list of dependencies could help.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: now i am getting  " cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter. It does not implement cucumber.api.Plugin"

Comment: @user3262269 Cucumber 2.0 yet to be supported.Issue created here - https://github.com/email2vimalraj/CucumberExtentReporter/issues/75