# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/api/formatter/Formatter on running a .feature file

Tags: java, cucumber

I am trying to run a simple .feature file in order to generate the required code for the Step file, however the following exception is returned:

Below is the pom file:

```
 <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-html -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Extent Reports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.26-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

and below is the exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/api/formatter/Formatter
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1009)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1009)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.loadClass(PluginFactory.java:173)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.pluginClass(PluginFactory.java:165)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.getPluginClass(PluginFactory.java:226)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.isFormatterName(PluginFactory.java:195)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$ParsedPluginData.addPluginName(RuntimeOptions.java:365)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:125)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:85)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:78)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:70)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:31)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.formatter.Formatter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
... 29 more
```

I have found many similar questions that refer to NoClassDefFoundError exception but they are related to **gherkin/formatter/Reporter** and not to **cucumber/api/formatter/Formatter**

For instance: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter for Cucumber with extent reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219492/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-gherkin-formatter-reporter-for-cucumber-with-ext)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following dependency might help.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Finally it was related to the Cucumber plugin.
I uninstalled/reinstalled it and it works
Thanks anyways :)